# Reading Text File Data and writing to TextArea

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, scrollpane

So I have a few basic questions that are probably going to be very simple for you guys. Keep in mind, I am not a programmer. I'm just a low-level IT support person who took a few programming courses in high school.

I've got an Announcements program I'm trying to build in Java. The program will launch in a Java applet, and I want it to accept input from an "announcements.txt" file (which will be what we edit with new announcements) and then display it in the applet. I am using the latest version of NetBeans to stumble my way through this.

The program will be added to a group policy in Active Directory to launch at login for all employees.

My questions are:

1. Can I just use FileOutputStream to write the "announcements.txt" to a TextArea? I've only ever dealt with console applications.
2. I added a ScrollPane to the applet design, and just placed a TextArea over top of it. Is this how it is meant to be done? Will it automatically insert scroll bars when it goes outside the window or am I supposed to output the text directly to the ScrollPane?

Sorry if this all seems kind of basic. I'm an aspiring programmer, but I've got a LOT of work ahead of me before I become even semi-proficient. ANY INPUT IS APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: 1st up  use Swing (`JApplet`, `JTextArea`, `JScrollPane`) as opposed to AWT (`Applet`, `TextArea` etc.).  2nd, don't use an applet for this, instead use server side functionality (PHP, JSP, ASP, Servlet etc.)

Answer (score 2):

1. No.

   1. A `JTextArea` can accept an **input** stream to read from.
   2. An applet must access 'application' resources by URL.
2. With the Swing equivalents, yes.  With the AWT equivalents, the `ScrollPane` is not needed, since a `TextArea` has inbuilt scrollable ability.